# What's the correct syntax to populate a Dictionary having nested Lists as value?

Tags: c#, list, generics, dictionary

I am new to C# and I am trying to define a Dictionary having:

as key:

> a string

as value:

> a List of Lists of strings.

What I could came up (not entirely sure it's right?) is this:

```
var peopleWithManyAddresses = new Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>> {};
```

Now, if the above is right, I would like to know how to populate *one* item of `peopleWithManyAddresses`.

Intellisense is telling me that the following is correct only up until "Lucas":

```
peopleWithManyAddresses.Add("Lucas", { {"first", "address"}, {"second", "address"} });
```

What's the correct syntax for it?

P.S. I know I could use a class, but for learning purposes I'd like to do it this way for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To initialize the `List<List<string>>` object, you have to use the `new List<List<string>> { ... }` syntax. And to initialize each sub list you have to use a similar syntax, i.e. `new List<string> {... }`. Here is an example:

```
var peopleWithManyAddresses = new Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>>();

peopleWithManyAddresses.Add("Lucas", new List<List<string>>
{
    new List<string> { "first", "address" },
    new List<string> { "second", "address" }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your initialization statement is correct.

Using C# 6.0, you can use the following syntax to populate one item:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>>
{
    ["Lucas"] = new[]
    {
        new[] { "first", "address" }.ToList(),
        new[] { "second", "address" }.ToList(),
    }.ToList()
};
```

You could use the following to populate two items:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>>
{
    ["Lucas"] = new[]
    {
        new[] { "first", "address" }.ToList(),
        new[] { "second", "address" }.ToList(),
    }.ToList(),
    ["Dan"] = new[]
    {
        new[] { "third", "phone" }.ToList(),
        new[] { "fourth", "phene" }.ToList(),
    }.ToList(),
};
```

If you want to add more data later, you can do the following:

```
dict["Bob"] = new[]
{
    new[] { "fifth", "mailing" }.ToList(),
    new[] { "sixth", "mailing" }.ToList(),
}.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. Is `new[] {"apples", "oranges", ...}.ToList()` basically an array being converted to a list? I wonder how this can inpact performance?

Comment: Yes, that is just a way to populate a list where you let the compiler figure out that the list is of type `string`. It should not impact performance at all.

Comment: @jj_ - The impact is minimal. The `.ToList()` overload uses an `Array.CopyTo` call to duplicate the elements and that's exceedingly fast. In fact, the `new List<string>() { "A", "B" }` syntax can be slower when there are a lot of elements being initialized as it is repeatedly calling `.Add` under the hood. I ran a test with both - when adding 12 elements to the list the `.ToList()` method was about 10% faster.

Answer (score 1):

first I create `List` separated from `Dictionary`:

```
List<string> someList = new List<string<();
var otherList = new List<List<string>>();
var peopleWithManyAddresses = new Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>> {};
```

First add strings in someList

```
someList.Add("first");
someList.Add("addresss");
```

Then add in otherList:

```
otherList.Add(someList);
```

Now create new List of strings:

```
var thirdList = new List<string>();
thirdList.Add("second");
thirdList.Add("addresss");
```

And add the last list of strings in other list and add in dictionary

```
otherList.Add(thirdList);
peopleWithManyAddresses.Add("Lucas", otherList);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for.. cutting it into little pieces... :) I avoided this approach it in order to learn more about c# syntax, but it's still nice to have it here.